# Getting the list of proprieties of a specific type using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to get the list of properties for an object of a specific type, I have made this static method to do the job.

ex: class A have 3 bool properties, calling GetPropertiesList< bool>(aInstance); will return a list with all the bool returning properties.

Is that ok or am I reinventing the wheel here?

```
    public static List<T> GetPropertiesList<T>(object obj)
    {
        var propList = new List<T>();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        //search
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(T)) { continue; }

            else
            {
                //Add to list
                var foundProp = (T)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
                propList.Add(foundProp);
            }
        }
        return propList;
    }
```

Comment: @varocarbas T is the type of the property, eg. bool, not the target object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are completely and absolutely right (might equal obj type or not). Just answered quickly; will correct it right away.

Comment: If you want a List of properties, why don't you store them in a List directly (instead of doing it in an array and then creating a List from it?).

Comment: @varocarbas because GetProperties returns an array. You'd have to convert the array to a List

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What I meant was: `List<PropertyInfo> properties = yo.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).ToList();` Technically, speaking should be more or less the same; but seeing two declarations and a loop which can easily be replaced with `.ToList()` does not sound too good (to me, at least).

Comment: Why? You earn nothing by converting then discarding the entries you don't want

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as you remember from my original comment, I was mistaken regarding the internal condition. If I would have read the code properly from the start, I might not have even suggested that. Now you are asking me why I said that and I was explaining my point. I don't like LINQ too much but in this context I would have gone for an approach on the lines of what you propose; and, in any case, have used the .ToList() bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work if `PropertyType` is a subclass of `T`. For example, if you have this class:

```
class SomeImages{
    public Bitmap Img1{get;set;}
    public Image Img2{get;set;}
}
```

Then `GetProperties<Image>(instanceOfSomeImages)` will only return Img2. Similarly, `GetProperties<Bitmap>(instanceOfSomeImages)` will only return Img1.

Instead of doing your check as `prop.PropertyType != typeof(T)`, you should probably do `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)`.

Finally, it's a little sloppy to have a `if(not isGood){continue;}else{doSomething;}`. It is much simpler to do `if(isGood){doSomething;}`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! Thanks for the tips. Anyway, I've changed the code to the @Panagiotis version using LINQ. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to shorten your query, eg:

```
obj.GetType()
   .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
   .Where(p=>typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
   .Select(p=>(T)p.GetValue(obj,null))
   .ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

You can also check the [Type.FindMembers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.findmembers.aspx) method which accepts a [MemberFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberfilter.aspx) delegate to filter the members it returns, but I don't think it would be much simpler or faster

Comment: Oh! I'm really not used to LINQ yet.. that's nice! Thank you!

Comment: Check the properties of the PropertyInfo class. There's a [CanWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.canwrite.aspx) property that should do what you want